# Dynamic search with pagination support in Laravel 5

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5

How can I allow the dynamic search to not just search through the first page, but all, using Laravel 5?

Jquery:

```
var $cells = $("tbody td");

$(".searchterm").keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim(this.value).toUpperCase();
    if (val === "")
        $cells.parent().show();
    else {
        $cells.parent().hide();
        $cells.filter(function() {
            return -1 != $(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(val); }).parent().show();
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
public function index()
{
    $ban = DB::table("bans")->select(['id', 'userid', 'banned_by', 'date_issued'])->orderBy("date_issued", "asc")->paginate(15);

    return view("bans")->with('bans', $ban);
}
```

Web.php route:

```
Route::get('bans', 'BanController@index');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code. I think it helps you.

```
function tableSearch() {

    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    input = document.getElementById("txtSearch");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    style = '';
    tr = $('#tbCustomer tbody tr');///table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

        for (var j = 1; j < td.length; j++) {

            if ($(td[j]).attr('style') != "display:none;") {

                if (td[j]) {

                    if (tr[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {

                        style = 'table-row';
                    } else {
                        style = 'none';
                        //break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $(tr[i]).css('display', style);
    }

    tr = $('#tbCustomer tbody tr:visible');

    if (tr.length <= 0) {
        var tdata = '';
        var trow = '';
        tdata = '<td colspan="11" class="text-center alert alert-warning">No data found !</td>';
        trow = '<tr data-id="0001">' + tdata + '</tr>'
        $('#tbCustomer tbody ').append(trow);
        $('#tbCustomer tfoot ').hide();
    }
    pagination($('#tbCustomer tbody tr:visible'));
}
```

Comment: Yes but how can it also show results from other pages like page 2, page 3 etc?

Comment: do you want to use the same method from other pages then you need the change


 tr = $('#tbCustomer tbody tr'); into  tr = $(selector);